# Text opacity in JavaScript on-scroll - how to handle it going from no opacity, to full, to none

Tags: javascript

I am trying to emulate the Apple Airpods page, and have the animation down. Now I am trying to render text on scroll, which is also working pretty well. The problem I have is that I cannot get the opacity to go from 0-1 on-scroll, and then from 1-0 again after some scrolls. Right now the text just sorta "drops" in, and then starts to fade out. I have tried  to change everything possible, but I cannot fathom how to reverse it, and how to make it do both in-and-out animation.

The code is as follows: (The text handling starts as "Text handler")

```
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.querySelector('.airpods-scrolling');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// index is the number we will be incrementing. index.toString = makes it from a number to a string, so it can be parsed. padStart = adds 4x0 om front of the number.
const currentFrame = index => (
`https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

// Handling how many images / frames we have
const frameCount = 147;

// Canvas height and width, same as image
canvas.height = 770;
canvas.width = 1158;
// Generating a new image.
const img = new Image();
// To add to dom put inside ()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
img.onload = function(){
// Drawing image inside canvas - 0, 0 is X and Y coords
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Function that updates the image
const updateImage = index => {
    // Passing index so it can update the image
    img.src = currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Handling changes when scrolling. Everytime we scroll this function is triggering
window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
    // Variable to get the scroll top value
    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    // Adding maximum value a user can scroll to
    const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    // Handling progress when scrolling
    const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    // Handling frame counting
    const frameIndex = Math.min(frameCount - 1, Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount));
    // Rendering the images over and over - using the updateImage function from earlier to refresh the rendering of canvas
    requestAnimationFrame( () => updateImage(frameIndex + 1));

// Text handler

    if(frameIndex < 10){
        var test = document.getElementById('textie');
        test.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if(frameIndex > 10 && frameIndex < 50){
        var test = document.getElementById('textie');
        test.style.display = 'inline-block';
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  test.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, -scroll / 500 + 2));
});
    }

// Text 2 handler

    if(frameIndex < 100){
        var test2 = document.getElementById('textietwo');
        test2.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if(frameIndex > 70 && frameIndex < 130){
        var test2 = document.getElementById('textietwo');
        test2.style.display = 'inline-block';
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  var scroll2 = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  test2.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, -scroll2 / 1255 + 2));
});
    }
});
```

```
html{
height: 100vh;
}

body{
background: #000;
height: 400vh;
}

canvas{
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
}

#textie{
display: none;
}

#textietwo{
display: none;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Image Scrolling Animation</title>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas class="airpods-scrolling"></canvas>
    <div id="textie" style="width: 1050px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; color: white; z-index: 10;text-align:center">
        <h1>This is working OK.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="textietwo" style="width: 1050px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; color: white; z-index: 10;text-align:center">
           <h1>This is working OK TOO.</h1>
            </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the inner `window` scroll event listeners – this creates extra confusion about when the code runs, as well as attached multiple of listeners on every scroll, with can quickly lead to high memory usage and then an unresponsive page.

Since you use `frameIndex` for initial "starting" points for the text, let's use that as a source of truth and use the value for calculating the `opacity` at any one point.

Remove any `display` property manipulation – this adds extra noise that we don't need. Let's just concentrate on the `opacity`.

Further explanation is provided in inline comments in the code below:

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.querySelector('.airpods-scrolling');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// index is the number we will be incrementing. index.toString = makes it from a number to a string, so it can be parsed. padStart = adds 4x0 om front of the number.
const currentFrame = index => (
`https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

// Handling how many images / frames we have
const frameCount = 147;

// Canvas height and width, same as image
canvas.height = 770;
canvas.width = 1158;
// Generating a new image.
const img = new Image();
// To add to dom put inside ()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
img.onload = function(){
// Drawing image inside canvas - 0, 0 is X and Y coords
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Function that updates the image
const updateImage = index => {
    // Passing index so it can update the image
    img.src = currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Handling changes when scrolling. Everytime we scroll this function is triggering
window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
    // Variable to get the scroll top value
    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    // Adding maximum value a user can scroll to
    const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    // Handling progress when scrolling
    const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    // Handling frame counting
    const frameIndex = Math.min(frameCount - 1, Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount));
    // Rendering the images over and over - using the updateImage function from earlier to refresh the rendering of canvas
    requestAnimationFrame( () => updateImage(frameIndex + 1));

    var test = document.getElementById('textie');

    // Have the opacity be `0` for less than 10.
    if (frameIndex < 10) {
      test.style.opacity = 0;
    // Between 10 and 50, have a sliding scale of opacity:
    } else if (frameIndex >= 10 && frameIndex < 50) {
      // At the minimum of 10 (for this if branch to be visited), then,
      // the calculation would be `(10 - 10) ÷ 20 = 0` which matches up
      // with less than 10 opacity of `0`. This then means that there
      // will be a seamless fade. At `30`, the calculation would be
      // `(30 - 10) ÷ 20 = 1` so this is the minimum for full opacity.
      test.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (frameIndex - 10) / 20));
    } else {
      // Beyond `frameIndex` `50`, this branch is visited. At minimum `50`,
      // the calculation would be `(70 - 50) ÷ 20 = 1` which matches up with
      // the maximum above. Then it gradually reduces down as `frameIndex`
      // increases until we go back to `0`.
      test.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (70 - frameIndex) / 20));
    }

    // Similar concepts for the conditional branches as above.
    var test2 = document.getElementById('textietwo');
    if (frameIndex < 70) {
      test2.style.opacity = 0;
    } else if (frameIndex >= 70 && frameIndex < 100) {
      test2.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (frameIndex - 70) / 20));
    } else {
      test2.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (130 - frameIndex) / 20));
    }
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  height: 400vh;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

#textie,
#textietwo {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Image Scrolling Animation</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas class="airpods-scrolling"></canvas>
  <div id="textie" style="width: 1050px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; color: white; z-index: 10;text-align:center">
    <h1>This is working OK.</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="textietwo" style="width: 1050px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; color: white; z-index: 10;text-align:center">
    <h1>This is working OK TOO.</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! And a lot simpler than my initial iteration. Very cool!